# A 'using' declaration with an enum

Tags: c++, enums, using-declaration

A *using* declaration does not seem to work with an enum type:

```
class Sample{
    public:
        enum Colour {RED, BLUE, GREEN};
}

using Sample::Colour;
```

does not work!

Do we need to add a *using* declaration for every  enumerators of enum type? Like below:

```
using sample::Colour::RED;
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do this

Comment: Not really relevant to your question per se but I would strongly advise you not to use all-uppercase identifiers for enums and constants. Preprocessor #defines are usually all-uppercase in C/C++ and they -will- mangle other symbols with the same name.

Comment: Using the scope resolution operator :: on enums (as in "sample::Colour::RED") is a compiler-specific extension, not standard C++.

Comment: To see more about what bk1e said on this being non-standard, see this stack overflow question: [Scope resolution operator on enums a compiler-specific extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/441552/1248889)

Comment: @Jonathan Gawrych: The linked question is from '09 and the answers there no longer apply in '18.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A class does not define a namespace, and therefore "using" isn't applicable here.

Also, you need to make the enum public.

If you're trying to use the enum within the same class, here's an example:

```
class Sample {
 public:
  enum Colour { RED, BLUE, GREEN };

  void foo();
}

void Sample::foo() {
  Colour foo = RED;
}
```

And to access it from outside the class:

```
void bar() {
  Sample::Colour colour = Sample::RED;
}
```

Comment: A class, among other things, functions also as a namespace. Anything that works with ordinary namespaces but not with classes is therefore surprising.

Answer (score 11):

To add to [Steve Lacey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum#438210), the problem with the original code is that you refer to a member, but the *using* declaration is not itself a member declaration:

7.3.3/6 has:

> A using-declaration for a class member
> shall be a member-declaration.

To highlight this, the following example does work:

```
class Sample
{
public:
  enum Colour { RED,BLUE,GREEN};
};

class Derived : public Sample
{
public:
  using Sample::Colour;  // OK
};
```

Finally, as [pointed out by Igor Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum#438214), even if you move the enum definition into a namespace, thereby allowing the *using* declaration, the *using* declaration will only declare the name of the enum type into the namespace (the 2003 standard reference is 7.3.3/2).

```
namespace Sample
{
  enum Colour { RED,BLUE,GREEN};
}

using Sample::Colour;
using Sample::BLUE;


void foo ()
{
  int j = BLUE; // OK
  int i = RED;  // ERROR
}
```

**Dependent Base Types**

To allow for partial and explicit specializations, when the compiler parses a class template. it does not perform any lookups in dependent base classes.  As a result, the following variation with Sample as a template does not compile:

```
template <typename T>
class Sample
{
public:
  enum Colour { RED,BLUE,GREEN};
};

template <typename T>
class Derived : public Sample<T>
{
public:
  using Sample<T>::Colour;  // What kind of entity is Colour?

  Colour foo ()     // Not OK!
  {
  return this->RED;
  }
};
```

The problem is that `Derived::Colour` is treated as an object by the compiler (14.6/2):

> A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified by the keyword typename.

Looking at the two conditions for the name to be a type:

1. Lookup for `Colour` doesn't find a type because the dependent base `Sample<T>` is not searched.
2. The name is not qualified by `typename`

The example therefore needs the `typename` keyword:

```
template <typename T>
class Derived : public Sample<T>
{
public:
  using typename Sample<T>::Colour;  // Colour is treated as a typedef-name

  Colour foo ()  // OK
  {
  return this->RED;
  }
};
```

**Note:**  The 1998 version of the standard didn't allow `typename` to be used with a using declaration and so the above fix was not possible.  See *[Accessing types from dependent base classes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1071119/11698)* and *[CWG11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#11)*.

Comment: In your first example, can you explain why the sample does _not_ work with `template <typename T> class Sample` and `template <typename T> class Derived : public Sample<T>`?

Answer (score 5):

C++ Standard, 7.3.3.1:

> The member name specified in a
>   using-declaration is declared in the
>   declarative region in which the
>   using-declaration appears. [ Note:
>   only the specified name is so
>   declared; specifying an enumeration
>   name in a using-declaration does not
>   declare its enumerators in the
>   using-declaration’s declarative
>   region. —end note ]

Comment: C++ Standard or A Night at the Opera? (Sorry, couldn't resist).

Comment: Could you explain me this idiom, I'm not very strong in English? :)

Comment: I am not sure the standard is written in English. Looks a lot like lawyer speak :-)

Comment: Actually, I meant "C++ Standard or A Night at the Opera?"

Answer (score 5):

By now, there's a related question: ['using enum' in C++20](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57913492/use-using-enum-in-c20-in-classes-possible).

It looks like C++20 will have the option make a `using enum` declaration, thus finally allowing direct access to an enum class' members, like this ([source](http://eel.is/c++draft/enum.udecl)):

```
enum class fruit {
    orange,
    apple,
};

struct S {
  using enum fruit;             // OK, introduces orange and apple into S
};
void f() {
  S s;
  s.orange;                     // OK, names fruit​::​orange
  S::orange;                    // OK, names fruit​::​orange
}
```

Of course, that means that inside `S`, you will also be able to simply use `orange` and `apple` instead of `fruit::orange` and `fruit::apple`.

Comment: It is [2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20). Perhaps [update the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58234069/edit) (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today)?

Comment: I don't see the point in that, especially, because the content would stay exactly the same. Is that a SO thing?