# Scope resolution operator on enums a compiler-specific extension?

Tags: c++, standards

On [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum), there's [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum#439055) that states:

> You can use typedef to make Colour enumeration type accessible without specifying it's "full name".
>
> ```
> typedef Sample::Colour Colour;
> Colour c = Colour::BLUE;
> ```

That sounds correct to me, but someone down-voted it and left this comment:

> Using the scope resolution operator :: on enums (as in "Colour::BLUE") is a compiler-specific extension, not standard C++

Is that true? I believe I've used that on both MSVC and GCC, though I'm not certain of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried the following code:

```
enum test
{
    t1, t2, t3
};

void main() 
{
    test t = test::t1;
}
```

Visual C++ 9 compiled it with the following warning:

> warning C4482: nonstandard extension
>   used: enum 'test' used in qualified
>   name

Doesn't look like it's standard.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Now that I think of it, what I've used was the equivalent of `Sample::BLUE`, not `Colour::BLUE`. Thanks.

Comment: Note: it's not standard for C++98. It's standard in C++11.

Comment: @NicolBolas Yeah because now they recommend `enum class` in [C26812](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c26812?view=msvc-170) which _requires_ you to use scope resolution to use an `enum class` value

Answer (score 8):

**That is not standard.**

In C++11, you will be able to make scoped enums with an [enum class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Strongly_typed_enumerations) declaration.

With pre-C++11 compilers, to scope an enum, you will need to define the enum inside a struct or namespace.

Comment: Note: In C++11, you can use scoping for non-`class` `enum`s too. You just don't *have* to scope them the way you do with `enum class`.

Answer (score 5):

This is not allowed in C++98. However, staring from C++11 you can *optionally* use scope resolution operator with "old-style" enums

```
enum E { A };

int main()
{
  A;    // OK
  E::A; // Also OK
}
```

Both ways of referring to `A` are correct in C++11 and later.

Answer (score 4):

In standard c++, things to the left of "::" must be a class or namespace, enums don't count.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to get around it is to create a namespace that's the same name as the enumeration. That will effectively add the enumeration values into their own scope and you can use the name of the enumeration/namespace to refer to them. Of course it only works for enumerations that would otherwise exist in the global (or another namespace) scope.

There's also an article on this issue somewhere.