# doubt resolving namespaces in enums?

Tags: c++, enums

from the below question  i sort of get how enums and namespace scoping works

[Scope resolution operator on enums a compiler-specific extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441552/scope-resolution-operator-on-enums-a-compiler-specific-extension)

However with regard to test code below i'm confused as to why in the below code snippet:

1)  i can refer to return type in function signature as test_enum::foo_enum

2) however "using namespace test_enum::foo_enum" is not allowed

```
namespace  test_enum { 

   enum foo_enum { 

      INVALID, 
       VALID
    };
} 

// Case 1) this is allowed 
test_enum::foo_enum getvalue() {

     return test_enum::INVALID;

}

//Case 2) is not allowed 

using namespace test_enum::foo_enum;
```

is there a particular reason for not allowing case 2 ?
Also are "enums" more of  C style construct and better to avoid in C++ code ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `using namespace test_enum::foo_enum;` is not allowed is because `foo_enum` is not a namespace, it is an enum. What works is `using test_enum::foo_enum;`

I believe what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
namespace foo_enum {
    enum foo_enum_t {
        INVALID,
        VALID,
    };
}

using foo_enum::foo_enum_t;
```

This allows you to throw around `foo_enum_t` freely, but you still have to type out `foo_enum::INVALID` or `foo_enum::VALID`

Comment: I agree with the namespace-scoped enum pattern.  We have a similar coding guideline in place on my team.

Comment: POSIX reserves identifiers ending in `_t`, so they're best avoided in code intending to be portable.