# How to change the integer type used by an enum (C++)?

Tags: c++, c, enums

If I have an C++ enum:

```
enum Foo
{
  Bar,
  Baz,
  Bork,
};
```

How do I tell the compiler to use a `uint16_t` to actually store the value of the enum?

EDIT: Does GCC support this feature in its implementation of C++11?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer, standard changed and topic on the link does not tell about `enum class`

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: Not at all. I want to know if I can change enum to store its values internally with a `uint16_t`, not whether it is the same size as `int`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You cannot do this in C++98/03. C++11 does allow you to do it, and *without* `enum class` the way everyone else seems to keep telling you:

```
enum EnumType : uint16_t
{
  Bar,
  Baz,
  Bork,
};
```

Again, you don't have to use `enum class`. Not that it's a bad idea, but you don't *have* to.

---

> Does GCC support this feature in its implementation of C++11?

[Which version of GCC?](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) It looks like GCC 4.4 added this functionality, but you should probably look to more recent versions, just for the sake of stability.

Comment: I was wondering that myself. The only difference is that `enum class` creates a new scope, whereas `enum` does not.

Comment: @chris: No, there are several differences between `enum class` and `enum`. Both do create scopes (the above `Bar` can be accessed with `EnumType::Bar`), but only the `class` version *forces* you to use the scoped enum. Also, `enum class` variables do not *implicitly* convert integers to the enumeration type. So you must either pass an actual enumerator of the correct type, or you must perform an explicit cast. This adds a *lot* more type safety.

Comment: Oh, I got my point from another question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441552/scope-resolution-operator-on-enums-a-compiler-specific-extension As for your second point, I simply never heard about that one. Thanks for the free knowledge :)

Answer (score 20):

In C++11, you can do that:

```
enum class Foo : uint16_t 
{
  Bar,
  Baz,
  Bork,
};
```

Later on, you can also [know the underlying type of the enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343329/how-to-know-underlying-type-of-class-enum-c11x) as:

```
#include <type_traits> 

std::underlying_type<Foo>::type v = 10; //v is uint16_t
```

Answer (score 6):

With `c++11` you now have [`enum class`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum), that allows you to set underlying type explicitly:

```
enum class Foo: uint16_t 
{ 
   Bar,
   Baz,
   Bork,
};
```

Answer (score 5):

With pre-C++2011 you can force a minimum storage by using a suitable range of values:

```
enum foo {
    v0 = 0,
    vmax = 32767
};
```

I think the compiler is free to choose either a sign or an unsigned integer type as the underlying type. The above range enforced that the representation uses at least `short` as it underlying integer. Making it even one bigger may cause it to use `long` instead. Of course, this only forces a minimum range and the compiler is free to choose a bigger range. Also, with the above definition you are not allowed to stray outside the range `[0, 32767]`: if you really need a 16 bit range (at least) you need to use corresponding values).

Comment: Actually, there is a restriction on the size of the underlying type as well. [dcl.enum]/6 precises: except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`.