# Using declaration for inner types

Tags: c++

What is the reason that using declarations for class members are only allowed as a member declaration? I cannot do

```
struct Outer
{
    typedef int Inner;
};

void f()
{
// this doesn't work with C++14
     using Outer::Inner;
}
```

, but I think this would be fairly orthogonal with the intended semantics of using-declaratives to introduce a name declared somewhere else into the current region. It is explicitly restricted by the C++ standard

> 7.3.3/8: A using-declaration for a class member shall be a
>   member-declaration

, but I wonder why.

I think it would make the language more regular if it was allowed for inner-types (typedefs, classes etc) and defined to be identical to

```
// using Outer::Inner should be identical to
using Inner = Outer::Inner
```

, which is identical to the behavior for namespaces.

I know this question [has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126203/using-declaration-for-a-class-member-shall-be-a-member-declaration-c2003), but the accepted answer is that is forbidden because the standard says so. I am wondering if there any technical reasons behind it. In one of the comments, it is said that

> Making the Standard (and therefore all compilers) more complicated to
>   handle an unusual case that has a convenient workaround just doesn't
>   pass the cost-benefit test.

I would say that is an opinion rather than an argument. Changing it such that the language becomes more uniform is a huge benefit. Right now, you have to teach different things for doing the same thing. And if you remove the clause, the standard would become simpler, both because the size is reduced, but also because a (seamingly arbitrary) special case is removed.

To be more precise, I am looking for **technical reasons** why this is not allowed, e.g. places were it would create ambiguities or other problems.

Comment: That's also in the accepted answer. Quote: `Making the Standard (and therefore all compilers) more complicated to handle an unusual case that has a convenient workaround just doesn't pass the cost-benefit test.`

Comment: @user2079303 I've extended the answer with my argument why this is not the case.

Comment: I don't see what you're looking for that isn't already covered in that answer. I'm closing as a dupe. Put a bounty on it for more details if you really want but you're not going to get any.

Comment: If you feel so strongly that the "opinion" of the ISO Working Group is insufficient for practical use, submit a proposal to change it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As said in the question, I am looking for technical reasons. The standard does not give any, and I am not aware of any, but there may be reasons which lead to problems or ambiguities. Usually there are some. I am explicitly referring to the question, but it does not answer my question, because it does not give any reasons beyond the existence of the clause.

Comment: @Jens: Then ask on the _std-discussion_ group. But I maintain that there need not be "technical reasons": the note in the accepted answer in the dupe is _all the reason there needs to be_.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An answer that there are no technical reasons would be perfectly acceptable, I just don't know if there are any, so I asked. The accepted answer does not say anything about technical reasons, so I still think it does not answer my question, and given that I explicitly ask something beyond that question, it is not an exact duplicate. I will ask on std-discussion and see if there are some reasons.

Comment: You're obsessing over "technical reasons not to do something", but you have it backwards. There need to be reasons _to_ do something, and they need not be "technical" either.

Answer (score 2):

Do not confuse using-declarations and alias declarations. `using A = B;` is an *alias-declaration*, which semantically is the same as a typedef:

> A
>   typedef-name
>   can also be introduced by an
>   alias-declaration
>   . The
>   identifier
>   following the
>   using
>   keyword
>   becomes a
>   typedef-name
>   and the optional
>   attribute-specifier-seq
>   following the
>   identifier
>   appertains to that
>   typedef-name
>   . It has the same semantics as if it were introduced by the
>   typedef
>   specifier. In particular, it
>   does not define a new type and it shall not appear in the
>   type-id
>   .

So, you write `using Inner = Outer::Inner` because it's the same as `typedef Outer::Inner Inner`, not just `typedef Outer::Inner`. An *alias-declaration* makes an alias for a type name.

A *using-declaration*, on the other hand, is something different: it introduces a name into scope (7.3.3/1), but it is also invoked by the word `using`, which is somewhat confusing.

So,

> // using Outer::Inner should be identical to
>   using Inner = Outer::Inner

they can't be identical, they are different things.

Comment: I am referring to using declarations, e.g. `using namespace std::chrono::miliseconds`, which imports the name into the current scope. Now, I want to be able to do the same with `using Inner::Outer`, which is possible in member declarations, but not in scope blocks. I am wondering why, because I don't see a reason for this. The alias-declaration would be the intended semantics.