# difference between introducing using std::cout vs std::string::size_type to a source file

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, using

I have been using `using std::cout;` or `using std::cin`, etc., to introduce the names successfully to a source file and use them further in the functions of the file. I tried to do the same with `std::string::size_type` and ended up getting *'error: using-declaration for member at non-class scope'* in gcc and  *'error: not a valid using-declaration at non-class scope'* in MSVC compiler.

Here is the link to the code I have written : https://onlinegdb.com/-c6sJuZdrV.

Following is the relevant excerpt from it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
using std::string::size_type;

void Part_2()
{
   string s1, s2;
   cout << "Enter the first string" << endl;
   cin >> s1;
   cout << "Enter the second string" << endl;
   cin >> s2;
   size_type s1Size = s1.size();
   size_type s2Size = s2.size();
}
```

I expected `using std::string::size_type;` to work just like `using std::cout;`. I found this [Using declaration for a class member shall be a member declaration (C++2003)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126203/using-declaration-for-a-class-member-shall-be-a-member-declaration-c2003) related question, but that's for a different use-case.

How can I make my code work?

Comment: Note that it's very unusual to use `std::string::size_type`, since it's the same thing as `std::size_t` (which is way less verbose).

Comment: It feels like it is better to use companion types to library types that a generic type that exists in `std`. `s1.size()` returns a `string::size_type` value, so doesn't it make more sense to receive it in the variable of exact type which is `std::size_type`?

Comment: Yes, I've seen a few people who do this. But this is a very fringe style (except perhaps in template code, that has to deal with different containers that can have `size_type != size_t`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [using-declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration):

> can be used to introduce namespace members into other namespaces and block scopes, or to introduce base class members into derived class definitions

`std::cin` and `std::cout` are members of the `std` namespace, which is why you can import them into the global namespace with a `using`-declaration.

But `std::string::size_type` is not a namespace member, it is a class member, so you can't import it into the global namspace with a `using`-declaration, you can only import it into classes derived from `std::string`.

What you can do instead is use a [type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) to introduce an alias to the class member type, like this:

```
using size_type = std::string::size_type;
```