# Map namespaced enum in a class

Tags: c++, enums, namespaces

Assume I've code like this:

```
namespace foo {
  enum bar
  {
    fooBarA,
    fooBarB
  };
}

struct baz
{
  // TODO: map "bar" in this struct to make valid:
  bar returnSomething() { return fooBarA; }
};

// and also this:
void doSomething()
{
  baz myBaz;

  if( baz::fooBarA == myBaz.returnSomething() )
  { /* ... */ }
}
```

What kind of code could I put at the TODO section to make the rest valid? Some `using` or `typedef`?

PS: To avoid questions about the "why": The namespace is living in it's own header file and might be used by a few different classes that should agree on the values of `fooBarA` and `fooBarB` but also hide that they are based on `foo` as that's irrelevant for the guys using `baz`.

PPS: C++11 is allowed. Would `enum class` help?

PPPS: Other questions like [using declaration with enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438192/using-declaration-with-enum) handle the case where the enum is in a class and not directly in a namespace.

Comment: Yes, `foo::bar` would work - but it wouldn't let me hide the fact that `bar` is not a "member" of `baz` to the user of `baz`. Or in other words, I'd like `bar` to look like a full member of `baz`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way requires a small amount of work in foo namespace. But it should be transparent to existing user of foo::bar. Just enclose your foo::bar's values in some struct from which derive your baz class:

```
namespace foo {
  struct barValues
  {
    enum Values {
      fooBarA,
      fooBarB
   };
  };

  typedef barValues::Values bar;
  static const bar fooBarA = barValues::fooBarA;
  static const bar fooBarB = barValues::fooBarB;
}

struct baz : foo::barValues
{
  typedef foo::bar bar;
  bar returnSomething() { return fooBarA; }
};

// and also this:
void doSomething()
{
  baz myBaz;

  if( baz::fooBarA == myBaz.returnSomething() )
  { /* ... */ }
  if( foo::fooBarA == myBaz.returnSomething() )
  { /* ... */ }
}
```

Its advantage over other answer is that you enclose your foo::bar values in namespace foo - only there you add/modify/delete this enum values. This is safer I believe. Its disadvantage in comparison to other answer is that you have to modify other file which can't be an option.

Comment: Not the nice solution I hoped for but probably the best that's possible.

Comment: I was thinking about this - but could not find anything better. Maybe, if start with this syntax: `namespace foo { struct bar { enum Values { A, B }; }; }` then using as `foo::bar::A` everywhere - but for `baz` used as `baz::A`. Not sure if smarter but did not require to retype all names twice.

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
struct baz
{
    typedef foo::bar   bar;
    static const bar fooBarA = foo::fooBarA;
    static const bar fooBarB = foo::fooBarB;

  // This is now valid
  bar returnSomething() { return fooBarA; }
};
```

but I don't know if it is really useful. If your users try to overload some functions or something, they might be in for a surprise.

Comment: What is worse a maintainability hole is introduced. When someone modifies foo::bar - the baz must be changed too. Compiler will tell us about reducing or changing elements of foo::bar, but it will not say a word about extending foo::bar.

Comment: That would work but isn't quite useable. Imagine `bar` doesn't have two values but perhaps 100 different colors. Then every class using that enum would need additional 100 lines defining the values...

Comment: @Chris - Right, it is not very useful. On the other hand I don't know of any way to "import" enum values without mentioning each value separately. They are individual values, and not a package.